# How do I count total number of employees with expired certificates in MS Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, report, conditional-formatting, calculated-field

I'm creating an employee database of certificates w/ expiration dates.  I want to print quarterly reports for trainers to knows how many students will be due for a refresher before they expire.  With conditional formatting, I have displayed Red for expired (3 year limit on certificate); yellow for expiring w/in 90 days and no color for current. Now I would like to use a text box in MS Access Report to calculate how many employees are going to expire within 90 days and how many employees have already expired.  For example, I want to display that 22 employees are expired and 12 are expiring in 90 days automatically every time the report is run.  I tried using the expression below but there is an invalid syntax and I'm at a lost.  Please help!!

`[CourseName] < Now()-1095`

`=Sum(IIf([CourseName] <= Now()-1095,1,0))`

Comment: Why are you comparing CourseName with a date? Why would you subtract 1095 days?

Comment: My course name is Chainsaw and it shows as a date.  3 years = 1095 days.  i don't have extra columns to show the expired date since there are too many courses for each employee. With your suggestion, i replaced "Now" with "Date" and it fixed the syntax error!  Thanks!!!  Here's how it looks now. =Sum(IIf([Chainsaw]<=Date()-1095,1,0))

Answer (score 0):

For dates that are going to expire in the next quarter(ExpDate) is the course expiry date

```
=Sum(IIf([ExpDate]<=DateAdd("q",1,Date()) And [ExpDate]>=Date(),1,0))
```

& for expired dates

```
=Sum(IIf([ExpDate]<Date(),1,0))
```